# Stripe Connect code processed by AWS Amplify Auth

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, aws-amplify

In my Angular project, I have configured AWS Amplify with [OAuth and Hosted UI](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#oauth-and-hosted-ui).

Everything is working fine. When I want to connect with Google, I am redirected back with an url like http://localhost:4200/?code=de79bfa4-xxxxxx&state=2xxxxxx which is well handled by the AWS Amplify Hub.

Now, I want to configure **Stripe Connect** in my project which also use an [OAuth connection flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts).

So I configure my OAuth link as defined in the documentation by adding a link as below:

```
<a class="stripe-connect" href="https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_xxxxxx&scope=read_write"><span>Connect with Stripe</span></a>
```

**Problem**

I am redirected back with an url like http://localhost:4200/stripe?scope=read_write&code=ac_xxxxxx

Unfortunately, this url is also processed by Amplify and I got the following error message :

> zone.js:1152 POST https://[domain].amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token 400
>
> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: invalid_grant
>
> Error: invalid_grant

Which is understandable because Amplify try to handle Stripe Connect code..

But I don't know how to correct this behaviour.

Any idea to solve this problem?

**To Reproduce**

1. Configure the sample repository with Amplify Auth Hosted UI
2. Edit the Stripe client_id in `stripe.component.html`
3. Start the project
4. Connect with google
5. Navigate to Settings
6. Click on the link 'Connect with Stripe'
7. On the Stripe form, click 'Ignore this account form'
8. See the error

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Amplify team and this is the normal behaviour:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3157

> With the OAuth flows in Amplify and the code-grant flow, once you get
>   redirected back from the 3rd party Amplify will automatically parse
>   the URL to retrieve the code and use this to retrieve credentials from
>   the 3rd party /token endpoint.

Unfortunately, at this time we cannot add exceptions or even filters to Amplify to not automatically parse URL.